# Mysql Query in Background?

Tags: linux, mysql

How to insert the data into MYSQL DB  in background mode  ?

The data contains huge volume about 20 million rows

Comment: Just what is this supposed to mean? In background of what? for what purpose? in which context/environment? etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that by "background mode" you mean that you want lower priority for your INSERT statements to rule out concurrency and performance issues while feeding the database.

In this case, consider using the [INSERT DELAYED](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-delayed.html) statement for row insertion. From the MySQL docs:

> The DELAYED option for the INSERT statement is a MySQL extension to
>   standard SQL that is very useful if you have clients that cannot or
>   need not wait for the INSERT to complete. This is a common situation
>   when you use MySQL for logging and you also periodically run SELECT
>   and UPDATE statements that take a long time to complete.
>
> When a client uses INSERT DELAYED, it gets an okay from the server at
>   once, and the row is queued to be inserted when the table is not in
>   use by any other thread.
>
> Another major benefit of using INSERT DELAYED is that inserts from
>   many clients are bundled together and written in one block. This is
>   much faster than performing many separate inserts.

When inserting a large amount of data, consider temporarily disabling the [binary log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-log.html) to reduce the strain on your I/O subsystem.